# Why does the wrong image appear after I motion track it?

Tags: rendering

I made a blender scene, motion tracked an image, animated my bull model, then rendered and the image showed up. Then I wanted the bull in another image, so I went to the movie clip editor and added an additional image. I motion tracked, and even the camera perspective shows it. The problem is, when I render the first image shows up instead of the new one I added. I tried clicking the x on the first clip but that didn't work. The first picture shows the camera perspective with the image I want and the second image shows the image that it renders on, with the trackers from the previous render! [image: First image]
[image: second image]

Comment: unclick the sequencer on the post-porocessing section

Comment: @cegaton Where do I find the post processing section

Comment: @cegaton I found it but that doesn't work

Comment: can you edit your question and show your node setup? Did you modify the movie clip node to reflect the changes?